# How to refer to the type of the current class from a static method in C#

Tags: c#, class, reference

I've been trying to find an answer for this problem many times in the recent years but I always ended up sweeping it under the carpet with workarounds, referring to the class type by passing the type via argument.

My project is a class library and actually shouldn't allow that as the classes are responsible for vital database integrity and users sometimes seriously mess up things by simply passing the wrong type. There are many ways minimizing that, I know, by runtime checks (which is the case) but it's still causing recurring issues and I'd like to put an end to it once and for all with the proper solution.

Basically what I'm looking for is the equivalent of the `this` keyword or `typeof(this)` expression **for class, instead of its instance**.

Here is an example that demonstrates the problem:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected static void InitializeTaggedFields(Type aType)
    {
        ...
    }
}

// User defined custom class inheriting my Base class
public class StoreThis : Base
{
    [Tag("something")]
    string Field1;
    [Tag("something")]
    string Field2;
    [Tag("something_else")]
    string Field3;

    // This constructor should be in the Base class because user has
    // to pass the type of his current class each time to initialize
    // the class.
    public StoreThis()
    {
        InitializeTaggedFields(typeof(StoreThis));
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Why did you keep `InitializeTaggedFields` as static? Any specific reason?

Comment: CORRECTION: This constructor should be in the Base class _but_

Comment: Because that method must run on the_derived_ class and I have to pass it's type. And that's precisely what I want to put an end to once and for all: keep having to call that method externally.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the scenario, but why can't you simply have a default constructor in the base class that calls InitializeTaggedFields with "this.GetType()" as the parameter?

Comment: @user3411060 If you don't keep it static then also it will be open to be called for derived classes. then why do you want it to be static only.

Comment: just wondering, but what happens exactly inside the `InitializeTaggedFields` method? What does it do with that type parameter?

Comment: Willem: Becuase that `this.GetType()` would run on the `Base` class, instead the derived one. Jenish: That static method has many submethods which have to be static.

Comment: @user3411060: But the method accepts a System.Type, so presumably you want to work with a System.Type. If you just call InitializeTaggedFields(this.GetType()) from the base class, the System.Type passed will be of the actual instance (StoreThis in your example).

Comment: cgijbels: It scans all fields for tags and inserts them into a DB.

Comment: @user3411060: In which case  a base constructor calling IntializeTaggedFields(this.GetType()) will do the job.

Comment: Yeah, you're right mate, I just tried it out in a test program, it works! Thanks! My confusion with the `this` keyword was basically that _in which_ class the constructor was defined and _in which_ it was called from. An interesting anomaly I'd noticed in the test program, no matter whether I call `this.GetType()` or `base.GetType()` they both return with the type of the derived class. BTW, post it as an answer and I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood everything completely, what you want is simply this:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected static void InitializeTaggedFields(Type aType)
    {
        // aType will be of the instantiated type:
        // When a "StoreThis" is instantiated,
        // aType.Equals(typeof(StoreThis)) is true,
        // if a "StoreThat" was instatiated
        // aType.Equals(typeof(StoreThat)) is true.
        // etc, etc.
    }

    public Base()
    {
        InitializeTaggedFields(this.GetType());
    }
}

// User defined custom class inheriting my Base class
public class StoreThis : Base
{
    public StoreThis()
    {
    }
}

public class StoreThat : Base
{
    public StoreThat()
    {
    }
}
```

And probably, you'll want to make InitializeTaggedFields private, since it's not used elsewhere.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rtp7Uj you can also add boolean field to check weather derived class wants to call it or not.

Comment: Yeah, thanks mate, it solved it! I sent a comment above as I tried this out after your advice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that's not possible - and that is a good thing.

The simple reason is that in OOP a base class shouldn't use information that is inherent to the derived class.

Comment: Well that is precisely what `virtual` methods do: they always run on the instance of a _derived_ class instead of the base.

Comment: Not at all. When using inheritance, the base class hasn't any information whatsoever about the derived class.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `this.GetType()`

Comment: @golergka We're talking about a static context here. Reading the question helps ;-)...

Comment: Yeah, I was not expecting to get information from a derived class in base class, Thomas. What I was trying to achieve is getting that information when the derived class is initialized, but still, defining the related code in the base. `this.GetType()` solved the issue but unfortunately I already accepted as an answer posted by another commenter with the same answer. Anyway, thanks to you as well! And everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with your scenario, you could have a look at [the factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). You can let the factory fill out the tagged fields depending on the classtype.

Comment: I know the factory model, the problem is that significant part of my code would be runtime checks for all kind of user stupidity, so I'd like to keep it simple and compile-time safe.